# Which scholars praise the current Psalms?

Tags: islamic-scholar, reference-request, books, revelation

[Wikipedia says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_holy_books):

> The **current** Psalms are still praised by many Muslim scholars.

Since the Zabur is corrupted, I wondered which scholars, if any, actually praise this corrupted Psalms.

**Question:** Which scholars praise the current Psalms?

Comment: Well wikipedia offers two sources Abdullah Yusuf Ali's  The Holy Qur'an: Text, Translation and Commentary and Martin Lings's Mecca; Abdul Malik, In Thy Seed one may try it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al-Biqa'i, the 15th-century Shafi'i scholar, comes to mind. Walid Saleh (UToronto) wrote,

"He [al-Biqa'i] has a soft spot for the Psalms, and used the book in remarkably sensitive ways to convey to the Muslim reader the sorrow and tribulations of the Jews during the destruction of the First Temple. He not only defended the sanctity of the Hebrew Bible but--here is the rub--he used it extensively to explain the biblical material in the Qur'an."

https://www.academia.edu/12279601/Al-Biqai_Seen_through_Reuchlin_Reflections_on_the_Islamic_Relationships_with_the_Bible

Comment: I have not come across any writing that said that Al-Biqa'i "defended the sanctity of the Hebrew Bible." He definitely referred to previous scripture in hos _Nazm al-Dorrar_, but referring to books does not automatically mean defending their sanctity. Where specifically did he defend such sanctity?